# Get value of list view edittext in button click android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

i want to get listview item which i inflate in button click and in save button i want to get whatever i entered in listitem in my arraylist below is my code

```
public class AddNewPerson extends Activity {

private AtomPayListAdapter adapter;
Button mButtonSave;
private List<AtomPayment> items;
private List<AtomPayment> Finalitems;
AtomPayment mAtomPayment=new AtomPayment();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);
    mButtonSave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.EnterPays_saveAtomPayment);
    setupListViewAdapter();
    items=new ArrayList<>();
    Finalitems=new ArrayList<>();
    setupAddPaymentButton();
    mButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Finalitems",String.valueOf(items.size()));
            for (int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
            {
                Log.d("Name",items.get(i).getName());
                Log.d("Value",String.valueOf(items.get(i).getValue()));
            }
        }
    });
}

public void removeAtomPayOnClickHandler(View v) {
    AtomPayment itemToRemove = (AtomPayment)v.getTag();
    adapter.remove(itemToRemove);
    Finalitems.remove(itemToRemove);
}

private void setupListViewAdapter() {
    adapter = new AtomPayListAdapter(AddNewPerson.this, R.layout.atom_pay_list_item, new ArrayList<AtomPayment>());
    ListView atomPaysListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.EnterPays_atomPaysList);
    atomPaysListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.insert(new AtomPayment("", 0), 0);
}

private void setupAddPaymentButton() {
    findViewById(R.id.EnterPays_addAtomPayment).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            adapter.insert(new AtomPayment("", 0), 0);
            Finalitems.add(new AtomPayment("",0));
        }
    });
}

public class AtomPayListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AtomPayment> {

    public    String LOG_TAG = AtomPayListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<AtomPayment> items;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private Context context;

    public AtomPayListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<AtomPayment> items) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        Finalitems=items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
       final AtomPaymentHolder holder ;

        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new AtomPaymentHolder();
        holder.atomPayment = items.get(position);
        holder.removePaymentButton = (ImageButton)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
        holder.removePaymentButton.setTag(holder.atomPayment);

        holder.name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_name);
        setNameTextChangeListener(holder);
        holder.value = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_value);
        setValueTextListeners(holder);

        row.setTag(holder);

        setupItem(holder);


        return row;
    }

    private void setupItem(AtomPaymentHolder holder) {
        holder.name.setText(holder.atomPayment.getName());
        holder.value.setText(String.valueOf(holder.atomPayment.getValue()));
    }

    public   class AtomPaymentHolder {
        AtomPayment atomPayment;
        TextView name;
        TextView value;
        ImageButton removePaymentButton;
    }

    private void setNameTextChangeListener(final AtomPaymentHolder holder) {
        holder.name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                holder.atomPayment.setName(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
        });
    }

    private void setValueTextListeners(final AtomPaymentHolder holder) {
        holder.value.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                try{
                    holder.atomPayment.setValue(Double.parseDouble(s.toString()));

                }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "error reading double value: " + s.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }
          });
      }
  }
```

}

When i click on save button it is giving 0 item list in my custom arraylisy so how can i solve this ? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: try adding `notifyDataSetChanged()` at the end of your `onTextChanged()`

Comment: Mohammed Atif : i try as per your suggestion but still not working

Comment: In Onclick of your save, you are fetching data from `items` arrayList. But you are not adding any objects in that list.

Comment: Akshay Bhat :so tell me what should i do? if you have any idea post your answer i will try it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method in adapter which returns the list which it is using.
Like :

```
public ArrayList<AtomPayment> getList() {
    return items;
}
```

Then in onClick of save button call this method.
Like :

```
List<AtomPayment> paymentList = adapter.getList();
```

And use this list for further operations.

```
mButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    List<AtomPayment> paymentList = adapter.getList();
    Log.d("Finalitems",String.valueOf(paymentList.size()));
        for (int i=0;i<items.size();i++)
        {
            Log.d("Name",paymentList.get(i).getName());
            Log.d("Value",String.valueOf(paymentList.get(i).getValue()));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The way he was trying to access list without values, i suggest you to even mention where he needs to put that `List<AtomPayment> paymentList = adapter.getList()` method. :)